# How do I update Set in Dictionary for only one Key? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I am having a difficult time seeing my mistake. I'm trying to just update the set of values for one specific key in a dictionary at a time, except every key is getting updated.

```
final_df = dict.fromkeys({'a','b','c'}, {'1'})
final_df['a'].update({'1','2'})
final_df
```

Actual Output:
{'b': {'1', '2'}, 'a': {'1', '2'}, 'c': {'1', '2'}}

Desired Output:
{'a': {'1', '2'}, 'b': {'1'}, , 'c': {'1'}}

Also tried:

```
final_df = dict.fromkeys({'a','b','c'}, {'1'})
final_df['a'] = final_df['a'].update({'1','2'})
final_df
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple mistake. What you produce here:

```
final_df = dict.fromkeys({'a','b','c'}, {'1'})
```

is a dictionary that with the keys `a`, `b`, `c` all maps to the *same* set object `{'1'}`. Then, all subsequent mutation on the set like you did:

```
final_df['a'].update({'1','2'})
```

will mutate all mappings as they are all point to the same set object.

To solve this problem, you can consider dictionary comprehension, which will replicate the set object for each key:

```
>>> final_df = {k:{'1'} for k in {'a','b','c'}}
>>> final_df
{'c': {'1'}, 'a': {'1'}, 'b': {'1'}}
>>> final_df['a'].update({'2','3'})
>>> final_df
{'c': {'1'}, 'a': {'1', '3', '2'}, 'b': {'1'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.update` just assign:

```
final_df = dict.fromkeys({'a','b','c'}, {'1'})
final_df['a'] = {'1','2'}
print(final_df)
```

Comment: This is a simplified version from a much larger dataset. If I need to update the values for 1 key with an updated set, how can I do that for a specific key?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I needed union instead of update.

```
final_df = dict.fromkeys({'a','b','c'}, {'1'})
final_df['a'] = final_df['a'].union({'2'})
final_df
```

Output:

```
{'b': {'1'}, 'a': {'1', '2'}, 'c': {'1'}}
```

Comment: Not necessarily... The real difference you've made here is that you are making an _assignment_ to the key: `final_df['a'] = ...` A union is also significantly different from an update. It may not give yo uthe behavior you want in every case...